# Duplicating problem with args in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm building a discord bot with Discord.py and i am running into some trouble when using the *arg / **kwarg when getting the msg.content. Here's what the code looks like.

```
if msg.content.startswith('bonk'):
    var = str(msg.content)
    for arg in var:
        var += arg
        
        if ' ' in var:
            var = var.replace(' ', '+')
    print(var)
```

Result : `bonk+bonkersbonk+bonkers`
For some reason it duplicates when it should only be `bonk+bonkers`
Is there any reason why this is happening and if so how do i solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite enough info here but I’m going to make an assumption that if you were to put `print(msg.content)` just under the first `if` statement, it would display `bonk bonkers`.

This would mean that when you set the variable `var` To `msg.content`, `var` already is equal to `bonk bonkers`.

With that being said, when you are iterating over `var` in the for loop, `arg` is going to be set to every character of `bonk bonkers` which you are then appending to `var` which is duplicating it.

It looks like all you need to do to get the result you want is

```
if msg.content.startswith('bonk'):
    print(msg.content.replace(' ', '+'))
```

Comment: Just realized the problem! I didn't need to use arg statement and your solution worked, Thank you very much!